# How to Toggle Multiple Same Class of Lists

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This dropdown arrow will only open one dropdown and it will automatically close the open dropdown if I click another dropdown

index.html

```
 <ul>
     <li>
       <p><i class="fas fa-folder"></i> ERGEBNIS</p>
       <ul>
          <li>
             <p class="left"><i class="fas fa-folder"></i> EQA-ERGEBNIS1.csv <i class="fas fa-arrow-to-bottom"></i> <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i></p>
          </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
       <p><i class="fas fa-folder"></i> Testdaten-Sets   <i class="fal fa-chevron-down" id="arrow2" onclick="showSets()"></i></p>
       <div class="sets" id="sets">
          <ul>
             <li id="arrowSub">
               <p><i class="fas fa-folder"></i> Testdaten-Set 1 <i class="fal fa-chevron-down"></i></p>
               <div class="indiSet" id="indiSet">
                  <p><i class="fal fa-folder"></i> 1_R1.fastq</p>
                  <p><i class="fal fa-folder"></i> 1_R2.fastq</p>
                  <p><i class="fal fa-folder"></i> Koordinaten.bed</p>
                  <p><i class="fal fa-folder"></i> Ground_Truth.vcf</p>
               </div>
             </li>
             <li id="arrowSub">
               <p><i class="fas fa-folder"></i> Testdaten-Set 2 <i class="fal fa-chevron-down"></i></p>
               <div class="indiSet" id="indiSet">
                 <p><i class="fal fa-folder"></i> 2_R1.fastq</p>
                 <p><i class="fal fa-folder"></i> 2_R2.fastq</p>
                 <p><i class="fal fa-folder"></i> Koordinaten.bed</p>
                 <p><i class="fal fa-folder"></i> Ground_Truth.vcf</p>
               </div>
             </li>
             <li id="arrowSub">
               <p><i class="fas fa-folder"></i> Testdaten-Set 3 <i class="fal fa-chevron-down"></i></p>
               <div class="indiSet" id="indiSet">
                  <p><i class="fal fa-folder"></i> 3_R1.fastq</p>
                  <p><i class="fal fa-folder"></i> 3_R2.fastq</p>
                  <p><i class="fal fa-folder"></i> Koordinaten.bed</p>
                  <p><i class="fal fa-folder"></i> Ground_Truth.vcf</p>
               </div>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

app.js

```
const arrowSub = document.querySelectorAll("#arrowSub");
const arrowDrop = document.querySelectorAll("#indiSet");


function openSets(){
    
    let drop = document.querySelectorAll("#indiSet");

    for (let i = 0; i < drop.length; i++){
      if(drop[i].style.maxHeight){
        drop[i].style.maxHeight = null;
      }
      else {
        drop[i].style.maxHeight = drop[i].scrollHeight+5 + "px";
      }
    }
}

arrowSub.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', openSets);
});
```

but I ended up opening all the dropdown all the same time, any help? here is the pict [image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should refactor your html to have only unique ids.

Then, create two classes :

```
.indiset { 
    max-height: *yourinitialmaxheight*; 
}
li.active .indiset { 
    max-height: 0; 
}
```

On the click, remove the active class, and reapply it to the clicked element :

```
arrowSub.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(li) {
    document.querySelector("li.active").classList.toggle("active", false);
    li.classList.toggle("active",true);
  });
});
```